# Pass HTML code as input

Tags: java, html

I want to pass html code as input. I am using below code to pass input but it is only reading first html tag. rest of the string is ignored.  I am going to perform few more operation on the code and not just print the input.

sample input

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Your Title Here</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="FFFFFF">
<CENTER><IMG SRC="clouds.jpg" ALIGN="BOTTOM"> </CENTER>
<HR>
<a href="http://somegreatsite.com">Link Name</a>
is a link to another nifty site
<H1>This is a Header</H1>
<H2>This is a Medium Header</H2>
Send me mail at <a href="mailto:support@yourcompany.com">
support@yourcompany.com</a>.
<P> This is a new paragraph!
<P> <B>This is a new paragraph!</B>
<a href="http://somegreatsite.com">Link Name</a>
<BR> <B><I>This is a new sentence without a paragraph break, in bold italics.</I></B>
<HR>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

my code

```
 public class testsolution {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String url_input = null;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        while ( s.hasNextLine()){
            url_input = s.nextLine();

        }
        System.out.println(url_input);
    }
}
```

I have also tried below code but it is also not working

```
String url_input = null;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        if ( s.hasNextLine()){
            url_input = s.nextLine();

        }

        System.out.println(url_input);
```

I am just getting `<HTML>` as output. I want to pass entire code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are only reading the first line.  You need to have a loop to keep reading until you hit the end of input:

```
String url_input = null;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

while ( s.hasNextLine()){
    url_input = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println(url_input);
}
```

Notice how I replaced your `if` statement with `while` loop.  The other change is that your `System.out.println` should go together with the reading: if you read a line, then print it.

Comment: Your code is stuck in the infinite loop of input.  Also, can I store entire code in a string variable? I a going to perform few more operation on the code and not just print the input.

Comment: It shouldn't get stuck - if it does, then something else is amiss. And, yes, of course you can store it. Just append it to a StringBuffer or something similar.  Do remember that you need to explicitly add newline characters back in, as they are not included.

Comment: I have pasted the entire code above, it is going into infinite loop.